# How to shuffle an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to shuffle a Object, but I don't get it.

This is my code:

```
db.transaction(function (db) {
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE CxId = '" + xId + "'", [], function (db, result) {

        var s = result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.rows.length)];

        for (var i = 0, item = null; i < s.rows.length; i++) {
            item = s.rows.item(i);
            var sql =
                "INSERT INTO xxxx (xId, xxId, xxxx, xxxx, xxxx) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            var params = [item['xId'], item['xxId'], item['xxxxx'], 0, null];
            db.executeSql(sql, params);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I shuffle easy the result?

In the results are the following data:

ID_______Answer_______Result

1 _______xxxxx________true

2 _______yyyyy________true

3 _______uuuuu________false

And when I randomize it then should be the result:

ID_______Answer_______Result

3 _______uuuuu________false

2 _______yyyyy________true

1 _______xxxxx________true

or

ID_______Answer_______Result

2 _______yyyyy________true

3 _______uuuuu________false

1 _______xxxxx________true

Comment: shuffle? You want to randomize query results? just order by a random number (how depends on your db engine).

Comment: Why are you accessing a property of `result` that is a random number between `0` and `result.` **`rows`** `.length`? What do you expect that value to be?

Comment: Yes I want to randomize query results.

Answer (score 0):

Try an `ORDER BY RAND()` in your SQL